# Postgresql - Get list of users which have ordered a certain item

Tags: postgresql

I have a table filled with users and their orders. It looks like `(name text, orders text[])`. I want to get all the users who have ordered a certain item which I pass in. I tried doing a query like this:

```
SELECT name FROM customers WHERE ? = ANY (orders);
```

But this does not work because ? is what I'm searching for, and Postgresql interprets it as a column, so it is not valid syntax.

I want select all users that have a certain string (?) in their orders array. What is the proper syntax for this?

Is there any way to do this without rearranging the database? This is for a quick and dirty project, so there's no real need to worry about scalability.

Comment: `WHERE ? = ANY (orders);` is not a valid SQL syntax. What exactly are you doing? Please show us the real code.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to see if a string is contained in an array of text, but it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I've edited my question.

Comment: That's a pretty bad design. Why don't you properly normalize the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the contains operator:

```
SELECT name 
FROM customers 
WHERE orders @> array[?]
```

If you want to put that into a function, you can do something like this:

```
create function get_cust(p_order text)
  returns setof customers
as
$body$
  select * 
  from customers
  where orders @> array[p_order];
$body$
language sql;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/23c9e0/1

---

But this is really a poor database design. You should really take the time and properly normalize your model. Doing it properly even makes sense for "quick and dirty" database. Most large databases started as "quick and dirty" and then they grew, and grew.

A wise man (don't remember who) once said: "*if something is worth doing, it's also worth doing it properly*"

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks. How would you suggest normalizing the design?